# delete all non-duplicate rows but keep one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete, delete-row

In MySQL, I have a table like so

```
book | user | phone
445    a       69
445    g       75
445    e       22
445    l       55
332    w       57
332    u       34
332    v       87
881    o       49
```

I want to delete all the rows that contain the `book` `445` , and `book` `332` and randomly keep only one of them at the end.

So the table will become

```
book | user | phone
445    l       55
332    w       57
881    o       49
```

How do I do this in SQL? I use phyMyAdmin and PHP 5.6

Thanks

Comment: what logic determines `445,l` is kept rather than `445,a/g/e` ?

Comment: @AlexK. Nothing really. Is random. Just keep one of them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here u go:

```
DELETE FROM table1 t1, table1 t2 WHERE t1.user > t2.user AND t1.book = t2.book
```

substitute the table1 with your actual table name

Comment: This is an exact copy of my answer..?

Comment: that's true. Mine is 2 minutes earlier; but it's general knowledge, I guess. No harm, no foul ;-)

Comment: @noirepyh yup! May be I was typing the answer by then, did not realize. You want me to take back my answer?

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Excuse me, what is the `table1 t1, table1 t2` ? I guess `table1` is the name of my table, but t1, t2, where those came from? Are they dummy tables for passing data around while executing the query? Thanks

Comment: those are `table alias` just substitute `table1` as your table name

Comment: @slevin you should replace `table1` with your actual table name. `t1` and `t2` are aliases which reference this table.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Sorry for the late answer. Yes, worked perfectly.

Comment: @slevin glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you would use `join`.  Assuming `user` is unique for a give book:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select book, max(user) as maxuser
          from t
          group by book
         ) tt
         where t.book = tt.book and t.user < tt.maxuser;
```

Comment: Excuse me, I suppose t is the name of my table, right? So, what is `tt`? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `book, user` is unique:

```
DELETE t1 FROM `table` t1, `table` t2 WHERE t1.user > t2.user AND t1.book = t2.book
```

Change `>` to `<` if you'd like to keep the "highest" user.

Answer (score 0):

Simple changes on sagi comment could help you on a easy way:

```
DELETE FROM `YourTable`
        WHERE (`book`,`user`) NOT IN
                (SELECT * FROM (SELECT `book`,MAX(`user`) as id from `YourTable` GROUP BY `book`) as temp)
```